# Package Management for C++

Tags: c++, package-managers

I am working in a company that they build a project separated in components that are developed separately by different developer teams. Everything in C++.

They use a lot of libraries in common and to manage all of them, they created a tool to somehow relates the version of the project and versions of libraries.

The question is about the existence of some tool in the market that already does this:

I mean, If I go to this tool, I can download for example the version 4.0 of our project that has exactly the version 4.5 of the library 1 and 3.4 of library 2. If I click "Download", I will Download the source code (or binary) of this **entire** (project + libraries) project and the concrete version of each library.

For example if I want to Download another project of another developers in the company, using same libraries in different version or platforms, I only have to choose that and is gonna download the project 2 with library 1 version 5.0 and library 2 2.5, and so on.

Is there in the market any tool that aloud me to create some relations like that, and btw, connects with code repo (gitlab in our case)?

I checked Gradle, Conan, ... but they build, not manage "relations" between components.

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: Did you check build2?

Comment: Linux package managers already do all of this. They will automatically analyze each executable's shared library dependencies; and assuming that the dependent shared libraries are properly versioned they will enforce dependencies at installation time. The short answer: convert your applications to Linux. If they are already on Linux, fix your shared library versions (they must be broken, then) and let Linux's package managers do their job.

Comment: Everything is done in Windows, with VS2010 and visual compiler. There is no option to change the tools and platform to develop. Sadly this is not possible at all because we also use other tools to compile for real time systems later.

Comment: Gradle absolutely manages specific dependency versions! I use that all the time!

Comment: Conan also manages specific dependency versions.

Answer (score 7):

CMake provides enough functionality to create these kinds of relationships within your build system. Unfortunately you have to use CMake to manage the builds for all of your projects for this to work well. CMake does target Visual Studio as well as GCC, Clang, and ICC. If this interests you keep reading.

1. Use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to construct build configurations for your dependent projects.
2. Use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=externalproject_add) commands to express the dependencies of the parent projects.

   - ExternalProject supports Git as well as Mecurial, CSV, SVN, and direct tarball downloads.
   - You can specify the exact commit, tag, or branch in Git.
   - Supports Git authentication via SSL or Basic HTTP.
3. Run CMake against the parent project. All dependencies are downloaded and compiled automatically.

**Example Dependency**

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    Library1
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://git@gitlab.yourdomain.com/repo/library_1.git
    GIT_TAG tag_S.33.91
    HTTP_USERNAME ciserv
    HTTP_PASSWORD Obfusc@t3M3
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
        -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
        -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
)
target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE Library1)
```

There are several other commands within the ExternalProject module that can be used to further customize the dependency if required.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up @norman-b-lancaster's answer, consider looking into the [Hunter package manager](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter). It is based on CMake's ExternalProject feature and heavily focused on reproducible builds. Each Hunter release provides the CMake script required to lock down the package versions of all dependencies.

Your question suggests that you're concerned with package management within your company (as opposed to publicly available packages from ex: GitHub). Hunter's maintainers are aware of [this issue](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/521) and seem open to supporting it if the demand is present.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [cget](http://cget.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that provides a way to install a dependency just by pointing to the source tarball, which hosting services like github and gitlab provide. You can also provide a `requirements.txt` to install all the dependencies transitively as well.

It is cmake-based, which  it will install with very little changes, but it also supports other [non-cmake packages](http://cget.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/building.html#installing-non-cmake-packages). You can also create a distro of [recipes](http://cget.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/recipe.html) for handling packages that don't follow the standard configure, build and install workflow. There is also a lot recipes already available for many C++ projects already [here](https://github.com/pfultz2/cget-recipes).